# Run javascript on the first page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I only want to run a javascript method on the page load the 1st time only.  If there is a `postback` I do not want to run that method again.

This method is setting the defaults to certain textboxes.

If I add an `onLoad` to the body element it runs it each time on the `postback`.  I've tried a `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` but that too runs the method on the `postback` as well.

Am I going to have to do it old school where I have to increment a hidden value and check that each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try defining the method within your `Page_Load` event using the [`IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property to determine if it is the initial load or not :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     { 
         // It is the initial load, call your script
         ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...);
     }
}
```

The `Page_Load` event will be called every time that your page is loaded, regardless of a PostBack or not. It will only ever be false on the initial load, so if you place your call within there, it should only execute the script a single time.